# .Net assembly in VS2010 can use C++/CLI assembly of VS2008?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

My main project in C# is being developed using VS2010 and it is targeting .Net framework 2.0.

I have to now create a C++/CLI project which will be used by my main project/C#. This C++/CLI project (Mixed = native and .Net code) must of course target same .Net framework 2.0, but I can not build it using VS2010 because

Microsoft requires [VS2008/toolset v90] to be installed to be able to target .net 2.0 for a C++/CLI assembly

My question is, 
Will this create any compatibility issues given that my main C# project/Application is being built using VS2010 and its 'going to be' dependency C++/CLI Mixed assembly will be built using VS2008.
Or Is it perfectly safe to do it.?

Comment: It's safe, but you'll need the VS2008 redistributable to be installed on target machines. You also should be able to use VS2010 along with the v90 toolkit.

Comment: "but you'll need the VS2008 redistributable to be installed on target machines" on every client machine where software runs ?? Why is that, is it not the responsibility of the .Net run-time to execute the assemblies ??

Comment: Yes, on every client machine. It's the C++ runtime library, required by the native part of the code. Unlike for a pure C++ project, you can't link it statically, which is a shame.

Comment: That makes it completely useless in my case then, can you write it as an answer I will accept it //

Comment: Alternatively you could include msvcr90.dll alongside your app, just check if the license terms allow that kind of redistribution.

Comment: What if the entire native code is compiled as static library and then that lib is used/statically linked in C++/CLI project, does that still require VC2008 redistributables installed on client machines?

Comment: AFAIK the only way to get rid of the dependency is to compile with `/clr:pure`, but then you can't use mixed mode anymore. If you *really* don't want to depend on the rtl, build a native C interface and use P/Invoke in C#, but that could be more cumbersome. Like I said, perhaps you could simply include the required dll in your app.